# Asp Net Core DI for AutoMapper

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, automapper

I have a question regarding dependency injection for AutoMapper in ASP NET Core. I know that there is automapper extension for DI available when implementing custom `IValueResolver` and `IMemberValueResolver`. This works only if the custom value resolvers are created by AutoMapper/DI. This unfortunately does not work if I need to created the value resolver manually. Also please note that I DON'T WANT to pass items when I call `mapper.Map<>()` method, because I don't want the consumer of `IMapper` to have any awareness of any extra parameters at runtime

Consider the code below:

```
class Entity1
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; } 
}

class Dto1 
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; } 
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; } 
}
```

In MyProfile.cs

```
CreateMap<Entity1, Dto1>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CustomProperty, 
       opt => opt.ResolveUsing(new MyCustomPropertyResolver("Important value")));
```

And MyCustomPropertyResolver is like this:

```
public class MyCustomPropertyResolver : IValueResolver<Entity1, Dto1, string>
{
    string _someValue;
    public MyCustomPropertyResolver(string someValue)
    {
        _someValue = someValue;
    }
    string Resolve(Entity1 source, Dto1 destination, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        //I need IHttpContextAccessor ..... How can I do that???
    } 
}
```

Of course, If I did this:

```
CreateMap<Entity1, Dto1>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CustomProperty, 
       opt => opt.ResolveUsing<MyCustomPropertyResolver>()));
```

I can use DI and add `IHttpContextAccessor` to `MyCustomPropertyResolver` constructor, but then I won't be able to pass any extra params to the resolver that are also important to resolve the actual value. Is there a way to achieve this? The only way I was able to achieve this is by adding a static property on `MyProfile` class and set it via `ActionFilter` on the controller serving the request. Although this work but I don't like this solution because it creates unwanted dependencies. The official solution on AutoMapper is to do this:

```
// This solution is not good enough for my need
var dto = mapper.Map<Dto1>(entity, opt => { opt.Items["AnyThing"] = Whatever; });
```

With the above code I can pass `HttpContext` to the items dictionary, but this will make the mapper consumer required to pass in parameters that might not be aware of.

My code in reality is much more complex but it is conceptually using the same example above.

Comment: offtop: use a simple mapper [LynxMapper](https://github.com/gromanev/LynxMapper)

Answer (score -1):

**AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection** will automatically register any services that inherit from `IValueResolver` (and some other interfaces) with transient scope.
For this reason you need to ensure your custom resolver has a default consructor (otherwise, if your only constructor takes a string argument, you will get at error when AutoMapper attempts to automatically register your custom resolver).

```
public MyCustomPropertyResolver()
{
}
```

You can then create a map using an actual instance that calls your non default constructor (with the string argument):

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(x => x.CustomProperty, 
   opt => opt.MapFrom(new MyCustomPropertyResolver("Important value")));
```

Unfortunately, as you are not using DI to instantiate the custom resolver, DI will not be able to inject other services directly into the custom resolver. The work around is to inject these service into the resolver's consumer e.g. the controller, and pass them into the resolver through the Items collection:

```
_mapper.Map<Destination>(source, opts => { opts.Items["MyService"] = _myServiceInstance; });
```

**EDIT 1:**

For a more elegent solution where your custom resolver can avail of full dependency injection and also take a string argument in the constructor, consider the following:

Your custom resolver may look something like this:

```
public class MyCustomPropertyResolver : IValueResolver<Source, Destination, string>
{
    private readonly MyService _myService;
    // plus others you need/have registered

    // still need at least one constructor without the string!
    public MyCustomPropertyResolver(MyService _myService)
    {
        _myService = myService;
    }

    public MyCustomPropertyResolver(MyService myService, string fieldName)
    {
        _myService = myService;

        // do something important with fieldName
    }

    // rest excluded
}
```

Create a factory class for your custom resolver:

```
public class MyCustomPropertyResolverFactory
{
    static internal IServiceProvider _provider;
    public static void Configure(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _provider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public static MyCustomPropertyResolver CreateResolverFor(string importantValue)
    {
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyCustomPropertyResolver>(_provider, importantValue);
    }
}
```

Configure it in Startup.cs

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    MyCustomPropertyResolverFactory.Configure(app.ApplicationServices);

    // rest excluded
}
```

Use it in your map

```
CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
.ForMember(x => x.CustomProperty, 
   opt => opt.MapFrom(MyCustomPropertyResolverFactory.CreateResolverFor("Important value")));
```

Of course you could make the factory completely generic:

```
public class MyFactory
{
    static internal IServiceProvider _provider;
    public static void Configure(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _provider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public static T Create<T>(params object[] parameters)
    {
        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<T>(_provider, parameters);
    }
}
```

and use thus:

```
.ForMember(d => d.MyProperty, opt => opt.MapFrom(MyFactory.Create<MyResolver>("some string or any number of other parameters")))
```

Comment: That's false. The resolver will be created through DI so it can inject anything known to the DI engine.

Comment: Sure, if its another service, but go ahead and try it if the constructor takes a string argument as in the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, but that's a general problem with DI, it has little to do with AM. And your answer is still misleading at best. You can always rewrite it..

Comment: And he want both the value and the services injected.

Comment: As the OP notes, the additional services can be injected into the controller and passed into the custom resolver via IMappingOperationOptions.Items e.g. _mapper.Map<Destination>(source, opts => { opts.Items["MyService"] = _myServiceInstance; });

Comment: No, he says he doesn't want that :)